# managed extensible framework and AssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: c#, mef

Is it possible to add information to the `AssemblyInfo.cs` use the assembly attribute, e.g. `assembly:MyProjectAssembly,`

So that when the MEF scan the assemblies in the rutime folder it will only scan those decorated with `MyProjectAssembly`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MEF has this feature. I'm not 100% sure though.

What you could do is use [Mono.Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/wiki), a very powerful alternative to System.Reflection. `Mono.Cecil` allows you to inspect (and rewrite but that's another story) .NET assemblies without loading them. This means that you can easily add the functionality you are looking for. For example:

```
public static bool AssemblyIncludesCustomAttribute(string assemblyPath, string customAttributeName)
        {
            if (assemblyPath == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("assemblyPath");
            if (customAttributeName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("customAttributeName");            

            AssemblyDefinition assemblyDef = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyPath);

            return assemblyDef.CustomAttributes.Any(ca => ca.AttributeType.FullName == customAttributeName);
        }
```

Then use it like this:

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
            string dirPath = @".\Extensions";
            foreach (string assemblyFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirPath, "*.dll"))
            {
                if (AssemblyIncludesCustomAttribute("Blah.dll", "System.Reflection.AssemblyConfigurationAttribute"))
                {
                    catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(assemblyFile));                    
                }
            }
```